# Bios Network stack disabled after win 10 update

Tags: windows, wake-on-lan

I have configured the Wake-on-Lan feature on my PC to swith it on when I am outside., but when Windows 10 does an update, it disable the Network Stack and APM Power On in the BIOS, and Wake-on-Lan does not work anymore.

Can I stop windows from changing the bios or do something else to fix the problem?

Comment: try superuser.com

Comment: OK, I'll do it. Thank you.